# How do I fix error in generation the methods.section for EGAnet Package

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I am trying to run the methods.section command for the EGAnet package. When submitting the request for a method section for a EGA I get the below error.

```
methods.section(egaISIn)
Error in paste(intro.header, intro.text, corr.text, model.header, model.text,  : 
  object 'unidimensional.text' not found
```

However, the code works when I run it for the bootEGA

```
methods.section(bootISI)
```

Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: Hello and welcome! It's a R language related question, isn't it? Add a R tag to it, to add audience.